# convert numpy array of float64 values to datetime64 with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime64, time-frequency

If I have a **NumPy array** of **float64** values. I know these values represent dates in format of **datetime64[ns]**. I try to convert them with pandas. But I get an *ValueError: Inferred frequency 86400N from passed values does not conform to passed frequency N*

```
time = np.array([1420156200.0,1420242600.0,1420329000.0], dtype='float64')
pd.DatetimeIndex(time, freq='ns')
```

The time values must be *'2015-01-01T23:50:00.000000000', '2015-01-02T23:50:00.000000000', '2015-01-03T23:50:00.000000000'*. How can i archive this? Thanks!

Comment: [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with unit `s`, as follows:

```
time = np.array([1420156200.0,1420242600.0,1420329000.0], dtype='float64')
pd.to_datetime(time, unit='s')
```

**Result:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 23:50:00', '2015-01-02 23:50:00',
               '2015-01-03 23:50:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```